# Getting error while running android app (Unable to find explicit activity class)

Tags: android, performance, android-layout

```
10-25 05:30:06.560: W/dalvikvm(1428): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930)
10-25 05:30:06.670: E/AndroidRuntime(1428): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-25 05:30:06.670: E/AndroidRuntime(1428): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.example.androidhiv/com.example.androidhiv.AllProductsActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
10-25 05:30:06.670: E/AndroidRuntime(1428):     at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1618)
10-25 05:30:06.670: E/AndroidRuntime(1428):     at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1417)
10-25 05:30:06.670: E/AndroidRuntime(1428):     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3370)
10-25 05:30:06.670: E/AndroidRuntime(1428):     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3331)
10-25 05:30:06.670: E/AndroidRuntime(1428):     at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3566)
10-25 05:30:06.670: E/AndroidRuntime(1428):     at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3534)
10-25 05:30:06.670: E/AndroidRuntime(1428):     at com.example.androidhiv.MainScreenActivity$1.onClick(MainScreenActivity.java:31)
10-25 05:30:06.670: E/AndroidRuntime(1428):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4204)
10-25 05:30:06.670: E/AndroidRuntime(1428):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17355)
10-25 05:30:06.670: E/AndroidRuntime(1428):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
10-25 05:30:06.670: E/AndroidRuntime(1428):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
10-25 05:30:06.670: E/AndroidRuntime(1428):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-25 05:30:06.670: E/AndroidRuntime(1428):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
10-25 05:30:06.670: E/AndroidRuntime(1428):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-25 05:30:06.670: E/AndroidRuntime(1428):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-25 05:30:06.670: E/AndroidRuntime(1428):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
10-25 05:30:06.670: E/AndroidRuntime(1428):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
10-25 05:30:06.670: E/AndroidRuntime(1428):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Please show your android manifest file.

Comment: have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: `com.example.androidhiv.AllProductsActivity` declare it in manifest

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that this Activity is register in Android Manifeast

Answer (score 0):

You have not declared your Activity **AllProductsActivity** in your manifest file and the compiler is unable to find that Activity hence throwing error.

Declare Activity **AllProductsActivity** in your manifest file.

like this

```
<activity android:name="com.example.androidhiv.AllProductsActivity"
            ></activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

Its showing that you have not declared your `AllProductsActivity` in your manifest file.

```
  <activity
        android:name="com.example.androidhiv.AllProductsActivity"
        />
```

Answer (score 0):

You had to declare each and every `Acticity` which you want to show in your application it had to be declare in `AndroidManifest.xml` file.

```
<activity android:name="com.example.androidhiv.AllProductsActivity" />
```